# Understanding Reflexive Relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I'm reviewing some problems to try and get a better understanding of relations. I get how a reflexive relation works on a defined relation with numbers, but not so much when its done with a set builder of sorts.

Let $R$ = {$(a,b)|a + b$ is odd} be a relation on all integers.

My professor's answer to $R$ being reflexive is that "Let $a$ =2, 2 + 2 = 4 and 4 is not odd. Therefore, ℛ is not reflexive."

For a function to be reflexive if for all $x\in A$, $(a,a)\in R$, this is where my flaw of understand this comes in but doesn't that mean that unless the relation is defined then all relations are reflexive?

EDIT: for a relation being defined I meant this $R$ on {1,2,3} given by $R$ = {(1,1), (2,2), (2,3), (3,3)}.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  How can a relation not be defined and what would that have to do with (a,a) being in the relation or not?

Comment: for a relation being defined I meant this $R$ on {1,2,3} given by $R$ = {(1,1), (2,2), (2,3), (3,3)}.

Answer (score 2):

No.  The condition for reflexivity for a relation $R$ is that for *all* $a$ in the domain of $R$, $(a, a) \in R$.  If there is a single element $a$ in the domain such that $(a, a) \not\in R$, $R$ is not reflexive.

Answer (score 1):

Consider R = {(a,b)| a < b} be the relation "is less than".  This *is* a relation.  Any two numbers are either related this way or they are not.  This relation is not reflexive because 1 is not less than 1.

Actually, your professor just gave you a good counter-example (2,2) $\notin$ R whether R ={(a,b)| a + b = odd} or R = {(a,b)| a < b}.

Now consider R = {(a,b)| a + b = even} then R *is* reflexive because for all a, a+a = 2a is even.

Or consider R = {(a,b)| a = m*b where m is integer}.  Then 4 R 2 but 2 notR 4.  But for any a; a = 1*a so a R a, so R is reflexive (but not symmetric).

And here's an example where 3 R 3 but 2 not R 2.  R = {(a,b)|a and b odd}. (So *not* reflexive.)

And finally yours were R is reflexive and "nothing else" R = {(a,b)| a = b} = {(a,a)}

Comment: I meant this $R$ on {1,2,3} given by $R$ = {(1,1), (2,2), (2,3), (3,3)}. I'm trying to visualize it through a set builder with something like this so I can understand it I guess.

Comment: Maybe I'm starting to understand this better, I use (2,2) as an example for $aRa$, which means (2,2) is also $(a,b)$. From the given $a+b$ must be odd in order to be in our relation, since it isn't its not reflexive. Is that sort of the thinking behind it?

Comment: Well, yeah.... 3 and 4 are related as 3 + 4 = 7.  3 and 3 are not related because 3 + 6 is even.  5 and 7 aren't related but 5 and 14 are, etc.  It's not reflexive because for some a, a + a is not odd.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some serious hand-waving aiming at giving some intuition.

See the cartesian product $A \times A$ as some sort of "generalized grid", i.e. There is one row for all $a \in A$ as well as and one column for all $a \in A$.

If $(a,b) \in R$ then blacken the entry at row $a$ and column $b$.

$R$ is reflexive if and only if all entries on the main diagonal are blackened. Bingo !

Comment: Not too hand-wavy at all. Hopefully that paints a vivid picture for OP.

Comment: Kind of not hand wavy really.  "relationship" by it's very name implies an intuitive meaning but formally and constructively when we define things in terms of set notation, I think novices get confused that the definitions are too "subtle" rather than complex.  This does very well fit set notation which eventually has to become stronger than "intuitive meaning".

Comment: I thought I would get into trouble by saying "generalized grid". Since nobody is giving me a hard time bringing uncountable sets or whatever into the discussion, I draw the conclusion that humans are good by nature !